# ¿Como puedo esconder el codigo javascript de mi pagina web?

Tags: javascript, html5, login, contraseña

Estoy haciendo una pagina html donde los usuarios hacen login con javascript, mi problema es que al pulsar click derecho > ver codigo fuente de la pagina y ctrl + u pueden acceder a las contraseñas que tengo almacenadas en javascript, yo quisiera esconder las contraseñas en javascript para que nadie mas pueda verlas ¿como puedo hacer esto? he intentado bloquear el click derecho y funciono, pero aun pueden ver el codigo js con ctrl + u ¿alguien me ayuda? aqui dejo el codigo:

````
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login para varios usuario</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Ingresa Tus Datos 
</h1> 
<form name="login"> 
     <table width="200" border="0"> 
       <tr> 
         <th scope="row"><h2>Usuario</h2></th> 
         <td><span class="cnt"> 
           <input name="usuario" type="text" class="Input" value="" size="20" /> 
         </span></td> 
       </tr> 
       <tr> 
         <th height="33" scope="row"><h2>Clave</h2></th> 
         <td><span class="cnt"> 
           <input name="password" type="password" class="Input" value="" size="20" /> 
         </span></td> 
         <td><span class="cnt"> 
           <input value="Entrar" target="_parent" onclick="Login()" type="button" class="boton"/> 
         </span></td> 
       </tr> 
       <tr> 
         <th scope="row"><input type="reset" name="Borrar" id="Borrar" value="Reset" class="boton" /></th> 
       </tr> 
     </table> 
</form> 

<script language="JavaScript"> 
function Login(){ 
var done=0; 
var usuario=document.login.usuario.value; 
var password=document.login.password.value; 
var password1 = "cowgames123!";
var usuario1="nicolas";
if (usuario==usuario1 && password==password1) { 
window.location="TU_PAGINA_WEB.HTML"; 
} 
if (usuario=="USUARIO2" && password=="CONTRASEÑA2") { 
window.location="TU_PAGINA_WEB.HTML"; 
} 
if (usuario=="" && password=="") { 
window.location="errorpopup.html"; 
} 
} 
        </script> 
</center> 
<script language="Javascript"> 
<!-- Begin 
document.oncontextmenu = function(){return false} 
function right(e) { 
var msg = " ¡ No permitido ! Por favor ingresa tu nombre de USUARIO y tu CLAVE de lo contrario deja vacio las casillas y presiona ENTRAR. "; 
if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape' && e.which == 3) { 
alert(msg); // Delete this line to disable but not alert user 
return false; 
} 
else 
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' && event.button==2) { 
alert(msg); // Delete this line to disable but not alert user 
return false; 
} 
return true; 
} 
document.onmousedown = right; 
// End --> 
</script>
</body>
</html> ```
````

Comment: Bueno es que inicialmente ese no es el lugar para almacenar contraseñas y menos en texto plano

Comment: entonces en donde puedo almacenar las contraseñas?

Comment: Tal vez una bases de datos, (**solo por poner un ejemplo**) y debería quedar *hasheada*

Comment: Por cierto, que el código que muestras no es HTML5, ya que le falta la declaración [`<!DOCTYPE ...>`](https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) recomendada.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Ocultar elemento del código fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329365/ocultar-elemento-del-c%c3%b3digo-fuente)

Answer (score 1):

Como te han comentado ese no es el lugar para tener contraseñas, pero si lo tienes que tener ahí sí o sí, podrías cifrar la contraseña, en lugar de tenerla en texto plano .

Aunque aún así podrían ver el algoritmo con el que cifras y la podrían obtener , pero ya se lo complicas un poco más

Comment: Un ejemplo de como hacer lo que mencionas mejoraría el contenido de tu aporte

Comment: ¿podria usar node.js para cifrar la contraseña?

Comment: Ahora mismo estoy con el móvil no puedo subir un ejemplo. Si se podría usar node.js , pero si se usa node.js es porque hay parte de servidor , por lo que costaría lo mismo hacer un endpoint para hacer el login del usuario, y de esta manera quitas las contraseñas de cliente

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, no es el lugar para almacenar contraseñas.

De igual forma se me ocurre usar ofuscator para oculta tu código JavaScript:

https://obfuscator.io/

Esta herramienta transforma su código fuente JavaScript original en una nueva representación que es más difícil de entender. El resultado ofuscado tendrá la funcionalidad exacta del código original.

Comment: probe el ofuscador y funciono muy bien, gracias!