# ¿Cómo ocultar el resultado de una consulta en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, php7, pdo

Estoy insertando un video con la Api de YouTube, como se podrá notar en el código siguiente, la URL es traída con una consulta,  lo que trato de hacer es ocultar esta resultado para que no sea visible al publico, claro se puede ver la URL desde inspeccionar código, una idea que tuve es que donde va la URL del video se llame a una función que haga la consulta, pero me muestra el resultado como cadena. Me podrían dar un consejo en que solución puedo realizar, se los agradezco mucho, este es mi código:

index.php

```
    <?php
$sql = "SELECT url FROM videos WHERE id_video = 2"; 
$query = $connect -> prepare($sql); 
$query -> execute(); 
$results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

if($query -> rowCount() > 0)   { 
foreach($results as $result) { 
echo $result -> user;

   }
 }
?>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
var tag = document.createElement('script');
 
  tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        width: '750',
        height: '355',
        videoId: <?php echo $result -> user; ?>, // Aqui va URL Del video
        playerVars: {
        'controls' : 0,
        'modestbranding' : 1,
        'rel' : 0,
        'showinfo' : 0,
        'autoplay': 1,
        'mute' : 1
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿A qué te refieres con *ocultar la URL* y dónde aparece la misma y quieres ocultarla?

Comment: Por ejemplo, si inserto este iframe en mi web, las personas que sepan de desarrollo sabrán que al inspeccionar codigo pueden encontrar el link del video con el ID que youtube proporciona, lo que quiero es que no se vea ese ese ID. <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/(Aqui va el ID)"></iframe>. Mi pregunta no especifica que es el ID, una disculpa.

Comment: No puedes ocultar nada que esté destinado a ser mostrado del lado del cliente, sería algo así como mandarle una carta a alguien y al mismo tiempo querer que no la lea, mandando una hoja en blanco o el sobre vacío. Revisa las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/329365/29967).

Comment: Estuve viendo alguna información, este es lo que quiero realizar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNZiwYW9ALg&t=807s, pero al parecer funciona solo para archivos ya cargados

Comment: Podrías enmascarar la URL con un encode64 y decodificar con un decode ese proceso lo harías por PHP, pero creo no serviría porque es un iframe y si codificas el iframe vaya no se visualizara nada, y aún si lo pasas por el JS quedaría expuesto